# Multiple tables in .sdf file wp7/wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, sql-server-ce

Can I use multiple context to create a database (`.sdf`) file? I want to have multiple tables in a single `.sdf` file.

Eg.

1. Context `useraccount` with table schema
2. Context `messages` with table schema

What I have tried already:

```
using (dataContext accountdb = new dataContext(globalInfo.strConnectionString))
{
            if (accountdb.DatabaseExists() == false)
            {
                accountdb.CreateDatabase();
            }
            else
            {

            }
}
```

What I would like to so:

use account context and messages context to create a single `.sdf` file.

Thanks in advance for the help, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Having multiple contexts in the same database is not a good idea, it will cause you all sorts of pain - locking issues, inability to use the DatabaseSchemaUpdater class. You can have multiple tables in each context, and have multiple sdf files in your app. And the only way to do this would be to include an empty database with your app with both sets of tables already present.

Comment: I am aware of that scenario, where i can add an empty file generated by Visual Studio, but the user of the app would encrypt the database file when created at first run with a password. There lies the problem.

Comment: It is a good idea to reveal all information in your question...

Answer (score 2):

Guess no coder, must code when tired. The answer is easy, add the tables in a single context.

```
class dataContext:DataContext
{
    public dataContext(string connectionString): base(connectionString)
     {

     }
    //1------------
    public Table<account> accountees
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetTable<account>();
        }
    }
    //2--------------
     public Table<messages> messagees
     {
     get
     {
     return this.GetTable<messageCategory>();
     }
     }
    //3---------------
     public Table<test> testees
     {
         get
         {
             return this.GetTable<testCategory>();
         }
     }
}
```

Thanks ErikEJ for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Also, with convention, classes starts with capital and your property names.